# Getting a value from a .text function

Tags: jquery

I have functions in which values are constantly being calculated I am trying to store the value of these functions when the button is pressed however when I try the code below it doesn't work. How then can I capture this in a variable when a button is paused?

`songposition = $("#songCurrentpos").text(pad(Math.floor(current / 60), 2) + ":" + pad(Math.floor(current % 60), 2));`

`songlength = $("#songDuration").text(pad(Math.floor(duration / 60), 2) + ":" + pad(Math.floor(duration % 60), 2));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Set the values
$("#songCurrentpos").text(pad(Math.floor(current / 60), 2) + ":" + pad(Math.floor(current % 60), 2));
$("#songDuration").text(pad(Math.floor(duration / 60), 2) + ":" + pad(Math.floor(duration % 60), 2));

// Get the values
songposition = $("#songCurrentpos").text();
songlength = $("#songDuration").text();
```